# Problem sorting IntegerProperty in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html

Trying to work this out for a nice little updater across my web application. The only difference is rather than sorting on a StringProperty as shown in the example I am using an IntegerProperty.

No matter which way round I turn the query I cannot get it to respond correctly to my filters.

```
bfid = self.request.get("bfid", None)
if bfid == None:
  q = Course.all()
  q.order("-bfid")
  result = q.get()
  bfid = result.bfid

q = Course.all()
q.filter("bfid <=", bfid)
q.order("-bfid")
results = q.fetch(limit=2)

for result in results:
  print result.bfid
```

No matter what the bfid is, say 10, the two results it returns are 61, 62 which are the largest numbers in the set.

What have I done wrong???

Comment: Could you include the definition of the Course model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `bfid` to `int`; self.request.get() returns a string.

You also have a problem with your logic; if `bfid` is `None` the query will be done twice, the second time with all results less than or equal to `None`. (This isn't what's causing your problem here, though.)

Comment: oh sweet, doh! too used to php. oh i see what you mean about double query, just following the example, but i see why you says its not needed.